# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider- Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

Hi I am using spring batch for some automation task.  when I run the program getting following error and keep on trying  many way but doesn't work and I am  new in spring . I don't know how to solve this

Please suggest on how to clear this bug . would appreciate if you suggest.

```
'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ifmr.web.jobrunner.JobRunnerFtracUpload.main(JobRunnerFtracUpload.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

this is my POM xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>springcsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.track</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>com.track</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <jxl.version>2.6.12</jxl.version>
        <querydsl.version>2.5.0</querydsl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>${jxl.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.extensions/spring-security-saml2-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
     <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>nbxmarket</finalName>
        <plugins>   

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are messing around with your dependencies.

You have defined `spring.version` on top but for some dependencies you are using versions manually.

Try to keep all Spring Dependencies version as global `spring.version`

For eg: Your these Dependencies should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can always to go [Maven Repo site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm) and search Dependencies for your Spring version

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the use of Spring dependencies with different major versions.
You add the `spring core` 4th version and you have `spring-core` 3rd version as transient dependency which came with `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc` and so on.
In your case the fastest way to solve the problem could be switching to 3rd version of framework.
More efficient way to solve this problem and avoid the same in future is use `spring-boot` which contains [dependency bom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) or use `spring-framework-bom` dependency.

Example using bom in maven:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you don't need to specify the versions of dependencies which came from bom.

```
<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Some IDE's will tip you that you don't need to specify dependency version because of bom

[image: IDE tips]